# Is NginX good for Forums? Is NginX really fast?

Tags: apache, nginx, forum

I am migrating from a shared host to VPS for the first time and I am in a dilemma wondering if I need to go with NginX or still stick with Apache. Atm I use Apache for my site that runs on phpbb 3.0.11. It has forums along with static pages. When I was googling info on NginX, it appears to be faster than Apache and works well in serving static pages. So my questions are:

1) Is NginX good to use for forums?

2) How is NginX in serving Dynamic pages from MySql?

3) Is NginX really fast compared to Apache or is it overrated?

4) Do I stick with Apache or is it worth taking a chance and trying out NginX for my phpbb forum?

Any advise please.. I am in such a dilemma and I am hoping someone who have had practical experience with NginX and Apache can shed some lights!

Comment: Try it and see. Installing Nginx won't uninstall Apache. Their configs are separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know Apache, just stick with it.  The learning curve for Nginx is quite high, and not needed here if you haven't already done basic tuning.

Make sure that you are loading APC and memcached with say 16M cache.

Use APC for Opcode caching, and **acm_memcache** for variable caching.

This will make phpBB a *lot* faster.

Comment: Thank you so much TerryE. I will try your suggestion.